# How to get script variable value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using popup for showing message based on the id of click function.so i want get the id when popup is open in php. thanks in advance

```
<p>Link 1</p>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN564541" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog">test</a>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="modal hide" id="addBookDialog">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>some content</p>
        <?php //here i want to getting script variable value for database purpose?>

    </div>
</div>
```

and my script is

```
 $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
     var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
});
```

in ajax call i am getting the id from the next page but i want value in same page

```
function viwpost(id) { 

    var pid=id; 

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "view_more.php",  
        data: "pid=" + pid ,  
        success: function(data)
        {  
            $("#myModal21").html(data);         
        }  
    }); 
}
```

Comment: To get access to a javascript variable in PHP you need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery framework/API:

you can simply use the

`$.get('phpfile.php' { id: myBookId }).done(function (response) { alert(response); });`

your PHP file can pick the request up like this:

`$_GET['id'];`

> If you're trying to make a live pop-up to load the data, this is an incorrect method of doing so. PHP script is only loaded once on server running and sending a request will only give you a response so ensure you research.

I'd suggest you create your PHP file to echo out the data you want to pop-up.

Demonstration of PHP file to send a response back to the request (as requested):

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    echo 'what ever is outputted to the client will be received in the response';
}
```

Comment: how to use this..when i am using this there is no response.please give more example

Comment: Research about server-side code and client-side code. To receive a response, your server-side code needs to display something to the client. So `echo "this is the response";` -> send a request and your response will be `this is the response` - Ill append the answer

Comment: okey..i am using the onclick function to send a id to function that want by popup  <p class="pstyle1"><a  onclick="view(<?php echo $mem2['pid']; ?>);"><span class="qstn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal21">View More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></span></a></p> and this is my function:                                   function view(id)
{
 $.get('profile.php' { rid: id}).done(function (response) { alert(response); });

}                                                                                                                      in php:$_GET['rid']; there is no result

Comment: No, I asked if the `profile.php` is in the same **Directory** as the file you're sending the request from. Check your console for errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107230/discussion-between-kyle-e4k-and-dhamo-dharan).

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is mistake in getting id of the link. You can use like this -

first create input type hidden and set its id bookId in model body like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="bookId" />
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
    var myBookId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
});
```

Comment: i want to get the id value in php.not in html.